# Pandas new column based on old column with conditional to handle None value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a new column based on existing column in pandas. The existing column either contains a year and quarter. IE: "201901" or is blank. The new column should contain a complete timestamp if the original column has a valid entry or otherwise be blank.

IE:

> **Input**: 
>   201901 
>   201902 
>   None 
>   201901
>
> **Desired output**: 
>   datetime(2019,01,01)
>   datetime(2019,03,01) 
>   None
>   datetime(2019,01,01)

My attempt:

```
    df['stamp'] = np.where(df['quarter'].astype(str).str.len() == 8,\
       datetime( df['quarter'].astype(str).str[0:4].astype(int), \
                 df['quarter'].astype(str).str[4:6].astype(int)*3,1), \
    None)
```

Result:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

It seems to me that the code for the the True branch of the conditional is evaluating for all the rows. Note: the conditional is correct, it correctly identifies the valid entries.

Comment: should 201902 be 2019-04-01?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.to_datetime` will parse quarters automatically, but it needs to be in the format `2019Q3`, year followed by Q and the Quarter.

Since you have a column of integers with a `None` it's difficult to know if the underlying values are truly integers, or if they are cast to `float`, which could mess up the string slicing without first replacing.

```
import pandas as pd

s = df.stamp.astype(str).replace('\.0', '', regex=True) # Remove .replace if truly integer
pd.to_datetime(s.str[0:4] + 'Q' + s.str[-1], errors='coerce')

#0   2019-01-01
#1   2019-04-01
#2          NaT
#3   2019-01-01
#Name: stamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

You get some garbage `'nanQn'` or `'NoneQe'` for the missing rows, but since it's going to become `NaT` anyway probably not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just do something like...

```
df['stamp'] = df['quarter'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
```

and then do your other calculations?